# Columnstacked histograms in gnuplot from multiple files

Tags: visualization, gnuplot, histogram, data-visualization

I'm trying to use gnuplot to view some profiling data; I have several files, each of the following format:

```
file_runXX.dat:
elapsed time, stage
elapsed time, stage
```

For example:

```
0 foo
1 step_1
1.5 step_2
2.3 step_3
```

and

```
0 bar
0.75 step_1 
1.3 step_2
2.1 step_3
```

To plot them, I use:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram columnstack
plot for [i=1:2] sprintf("%02d.log", i) using 1
```

And I get a graph with two vertical bars: at x=0 I have a bar going from y=0 to y=1, then y=1 to y=1.5 and y=1.5 to y=2.3. At x=1, I have the same data from the second file.

Two questions:

(a) Is this the proper way to do this (i.e., it works, but is there something better?), and

(b) How can I set the xlabels to read "foo" and "bar" (see column 2, row 1, of each file)? I've tried messing around with `using 1:xtic(2)` or `title columnheader` and a few other options, but it seems that's only usable if I have one file containing both timestamps (I'm not sure I can do this, since I sometimes have `step 2a` in one file but not in the other; yes, I'm aware that this can mean the colors are not going to be uniform between bars).

Thanks

Comment: if you don't like those answers, please tell us why.

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation for a few days. It wasn't a complaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you could transpose the data:

```
#label  step_1  step_2  step_3
foo     1       1.5     2.3
bar     .75     1.3     2.1
```

... and then use following commands:

```
set style data histograms
set boxwidth .7
set style histogram rowstacked
plot for [COL=2:4] "all.dat" using COL:xticlabels(1)
```

this adds a legend which you can suppress or customize.

Answer (score 1):

you could combine all data in one tab-separated file all.dat:

```
foo bar
1   .75
1.5 1.3
2.3 2.1
```

and then use following commands:

```
set style data histograms
set style histogram columnstacked
set boxwidth .7
plot for [COL=1:2] "all.dat" using COL title columnhead
```

Comment: actually both my solutions answer only question b. regarding a: one file is better than multiple data files because this makes clear the irrelevance of the step_x labels. in your original suggestion you could delete the step_2 line from one file and the data still looks ok but the plot might break silently.